# Secure way to import database

Tags: php, mysql, bash

For a web application a database is created per organisation/ customer. I'm looking for a safe and reliable way to automate that.

Current situation:

- new entry is made in customer table
- php script runs to create database for customer
- php script does `proc_open()` to run a mysqldump and import, then sends mail to customer

It's pretty much automated but I don't like using `proc_open()`. We could move the `mysqldump` and import to a scheduled bash script as it's ok to have a few minutes delay.

The bash script would need a few user inputs, e.g. customer name, emailadres, creating a security threat.

What would be the best way to automate this process?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a cron job/script to check customer table and create new databases for new customers. You can use php **exec** method to run mysqldump and restore to database which is the fastest way. For security, do not write your mysql credentials inline with your commands! instead, use .my.cnf.

This is what i am using for years without problem.